# Show/hide div if it contains/not contains radio button value text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have a weird task on my new project. I have 2 radio buttons and I have to display certain dropdown divs based on the radio button selection. So radio buttons are 2 and divs are several more but I want it to show only certain divs, depending on radio button selection. I can't assign extra classes and IDs to the divs, so it came to me to try to make a javascript to check the value of radio and see, if it is contained in the div and display only divs that contain radio value. Here is the example:
EDIT: Added JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      var text = div.innerHTML;
      $("Radio1").not(text).hide();
      $(text).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="container">Radio1
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="Radio1">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container adult">Radio2
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<div class="select-items select-hide">
<div>1. Radio1 0</div>
<div>1.1. Radio1 - 1</div>
<div>1.2. Radio1 - 2</div>
<div>1.3. Radio1 - 3</div>
<div>1.4. Radio1 - 4</div>
<div>1.5. Radio1 - 5</div>
<div>1.5.1. Radio1 - 6</div>
<div>1.5.2. Radio1 - 7</div>
<div>1.5.3. Radio1 - 8 Loss</div>
<div>1.5.4. Radio1 - 9</div>
<div>1.6. Radio1 - 10</div>
<div>1.7. Radio1 - 11</div>
<div>2. Radio2 0</div>
<div>2.1. Radio2 - 1</div>
<div>2.2. Radio2 - 2</div>
<div>2.3. Radio2 - 3</div>
<div>2.4. Radio2 - 4</div>
</div>
```

EDIT2:
I forgot it should also affect another div with class select-selected to show the first of Radio2 divs. Now that is a bit tricky.

```
<div class="select-selected">1. Radio1 0</div>
```

This is on top of div with class select-hide.

I did not manage to make it. Any ideas how to do it or where to start over?

Regards!

Comment: you didn't try anything?

Comment: I tried. Just added edit with JS I tried.

Comment: You have to have some kind of identifier class or id. Or you have to get the inner text and parse it using regex or any other hack to operate on a specific collection of div or node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this... using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function xyz(){
    var getval = $('label.container input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    $('.select-items>div').each(function(){
      if($(this).text().indexOf(getval) > -1){
        $(this).show();
      }
      else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
  xyz();
  $('label.container input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    xyz();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="container">Radio1
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="Radio1">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container adult">Radio2
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<div class="select-items select-hide">
<div>1. Radio1 0</div>
<div>1.1. Radio1 - 1</div>
<div>1.2. Radio1 - 2</div>
<div>1.3. Radio1 - 3</div>
<div>1.4. Radio1 - 4</div>
<div>1.5. Radio1 - 5</div>
<div>1.5.1. Radio1 - 6</div>
<div>1.5.2. Radio1 - 7</div>
<div>1.5.3. Radio1 - 8 Loss</div>
<div>1.5.4. Radio1 - 9</div>
<div>1.6. Radio1 - 10</div>
<div>1.7. Radio1 - 11</div>
<div>2. Radio2 0</div>
<div>2.1. Radio2 - 1</div>
<div>2.2. Radio2 - 2</div>
<div>2.3. Radio2 - 3</div>
<div>2.4. Radio2 - 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could work, too, but it displays both by default. Calvin Nunes answer was better and accepted as answer. Thank you, too, for spending time to answer!

Comment: Great!! I think it was exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to apply this to another div on the page, too?

Comment: Yes, you can call the function xyz() anywhere on page, just change classes accordingly and you're done...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a change listener to both `input[radio]`, then inside the listener function, you select all divs, hide them, and then loop through each one checking it's content, if it contains the `radio.value` inside its `textContent` then show it.

See below code, if it helps

```js
$("input[name='radio']").on("change", (ev) => {
  let elem = ev.target;
  if (elem.checked){
    let divs = $(".select-hide div")
    let val = elem.value;
    divs.hide() 
    divs.removeClass("select-selected")
    divs.each((i, div) => {
      let text = div.textContent
      if (text.indexOf(val) > -1){
        div.style.display = "block"
        if (text.indexOf(val + " 0") > -1){
          div.className += " select-selected";
        }
      }
    })
  }
})

//below code is to call the change when doc starts, to let radio1 selected
$("input[value='Radio1']").trigger("change")
```

```css
.select-hide div{
  display: none;
}

.select-selected{
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="container">Radio1
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="Radio1">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container adult">Radio2
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<div class="select-items select-hide">
  <div>1. Radio1 0</div>
  <div>1.1. Radio1 - 1</div>
  <div>1.2. Radio1 - 2</div>
  <div>1.3. Radio1 - 3</div>
  <div>1.4. Radio1 - 4</div>
  <div>1.5. Radio1 - 5</div>
  <div>1.5.1. Radio1 - 6</div>
  <div>1.5.2. Radio1 - 7</div>
  <div>1.5.3. Radio1 - 8 Loss</div>
  <div>1.5.4. Radio1 - 9</div>
  <div>1.6. Radio1 - 10</div>
  <div>1.7. Radio1 - 11</div>
  <div>2. Radio2 0</div>
  <div>2.1. Radio2 - 1</div>
  <div>2.2. Radio2 - 2</div>
  <div>2.3. Radio2 - 3</div>
  <div>2.4. Radio2 - 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked wonders but it does not change the value of <div class="select-selected">1. Radio1 0</div>. How do I make it apply to another div with class select-selected? I forgot to add this one div that displays the selected option from the dropdowns.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your need now. If it is a new question, please, create another one here in SO, since your main/initial question is already answered

Comment: I would like to make it apply not only for class select-hide  but also for select-selected. Trying this...

    let divs = $(".select-hide .select-selected div")

Comment: Tried this but it did not work, either. The point is, it should work on another div, too.
    let divs = $(".select-hide div, .select-selected div")

Comment: Add an example of a `div` with class `.select-selected` because in the current code you posted, it doesn't exist, neither any dropdowns...

Comment: also, keep in mind that `$(".select-hide .select-selected div")` is **not** selecting 3 diferent classes at once, but selecting just the `div` element that is child of `.select-selected` that is child of `.select-hide`. That's why it won't work as you expect

Comment: Got it. I added the other div in the question.

Comment: I don't know exaclty if is this what you want, check my answer again, I edited it.
If it is not, then add a new question in SO since your are asking two different things in same question, which is not a good thing (see [ask])